# Google Play Alpha test links to production APK

Tags: android, google-play

I have my application published in Production in Google Play Store. Now I would like to provide new version for Alpha tests. I added testers to google groups, they have recieved proper link to test APK. But when they click on "download it", it links them to not Alpha, but Production version. It's already more then 1 day since I published the Alpha version. Anyone knows what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Somethings you can try are:

- Make sure that the version code for your Alpha APK is higher,
  otherwise it becomes inactive.
- Ensure that the testers have opted in. Your share link should be:

  `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/PACKAGE_NAME`
- Clearing cache/data and restarting your Google Play Store
  application. This might refresh the Play Store App to see any
  available updates.
- Make sure your app is in a published state. You **do not** need a production apk, but it shouldn't be in a draft or unpublished state.
- The device a user is testing may have to remove all other account except for the account invited to test. Multiple accounts *may* cause problems.